# changing menu structure - ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm building an app which contains 3 different parts, all those parts have their own menu structure. I would like to know how to update those in (as example) a settings page. I already made a start, but when I change the app, I have to refresh the app for the menu structure to show up.

**Settings.html**

```
<ion-list style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Taal</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" cancelText="Annuleer" (ngModelChange)="changeLang()">
      <ion-option value="nl">Nederlands</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="en">English</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="du">Deutsch</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Waarvoor wilt u de app gebruiken</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="type" cancelText="Annuleer" (ngModelChange)="changeType()">
      <ion-option value="alg">Algemeen</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="zrk">Zerken</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="kds">Kids</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

**Settings.ts**

```
changeLang() {
    console.log(this.language);
    this.storage.set('appLang', this.language);
  }

  changeType() {
    console.log(this.type);
    this.storage.set('appType', this.type);
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, public storage: Storage) {
    this.initializeApp();

      this.storage.get('appType').then((result) => {
        if(result == "alg") {
          this.pages = [
            { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
            { title: 'Website', component: HomePage }
          ]
          this.menuTitle = "Algemeen";
        } else if(result == "zrk") {
          this.pages = [
            { title: 'Home', component: ZerkhomePage },
            { title: 'Plattegrond', component: PlattegrondPage },
            { title: 'Overzicht', component: LijstPage }
          ]
          this.menuTitle = "Zerken";
        } else if(result == "kds") {
          this.pages = [
            { title: 'Home', component: KidshomePage },
            { title: 'Quiz', component: QuizPage },
            { title: 'Prijs', component: PrijsPage }
          ]
          this.menuTitle = "Kids";
        }
      })

  }
```

So what I kind of want is the app to 'refresh' after I made a change in my settings. I do know why this is not working, since the menu structure is loaded upon the start of the application.

Maybe someone knows a simple fix for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ionOpen` event. check this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/)

in your template `app.html`

```
<ion-menu (ionOpen)="omMenuOpen()">
```

and then in your 'app.component.ts'

```
omMenuOpen(){
   console.log('menu oppend.');
   //here set your pages
}
```

let me know if it worked.